# Passing diffrent account numbers to defined ads

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies

I have a template with various ads strategically placed.

I have multiple employees with their own Adsense accounts.

Depending on the employee publishing the data, their own adsense account number is passed to the ***data-ad-client*** variable in those ads so they receive any profit from them.

So one employees ads will be coded like:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:250px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-empOneAct"
data-ad-slot="templatesAdSlotID">
</ins>
```

And a seconds will be:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:250px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-empTwoAct"
data-ad-slot="templatesAdSlotID">
</ins>
```

Does the <ins tag need each employee to provide their own value for the data-ad-slot field?  Will I have to provide specs for each ad type to my employees so they can create them in their Adsense account to get a ***data-ad-slot*** ID for that ad?